# How to get label values dynamically and adding the numbers together from different input with reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Created a Div and inside it I have `label` element  and `input` element, I want to get different label values in each `div`. How to re-use my `div` component 
instead of coding the same code again.

I have tried to search in Stackoverflow plus googles, Haven't received a better answer.

Here I have created div element with just label and input element and then I have rendured this component in `App.js` file:
How can I reuse the same code/component to create 2 more div and having different labels values in it? Ho can I add numbers together from different input ( which I am getting from different components input)
Appreciate all your help!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './calculator.css';

class Boxes extends Component {

    state = {
        inputOne: '',
        inputtwo: '',
        inputthree: ''
    }


    getInputValue = (e) => {
        const value = e.target.value;
        console.log('value: ', value);
        this.setState({
            inputOne: Number(e.target.value)
        });  

    }

    render() { 
        const { value } = this.props // destructuring
        const {inputOne, inputtwo, inputthree } = this.state

        return (
                <div className="boxes">
                    <label className="boxeslevel" htmlFor="text">
                       {value}
                    </label>
                    <input 
                    name="text" 
                    type="text" 
                    onChange={this.getInputValue}
                    />                    
                </div>

          );
    }
}

export default Boxes;
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Boxes from './components/calculator';


class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
          <Boxes  value= {"Value 1:"} onChange={this.props.onChange}/>
          <Boxes  value= {"Value 2:"} onChange={this.props.onChange}/>
          <Boxes  value= {"Value 3:"} onChange={this.props.onChange}/>
          <ShowResult />
      </div>
    );
  }
  }


export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for the quick response, And yes by passing props it works. I have wrapped all the components Boxes in a wrapper div, so when I try to toggle it via toggle device toolbar ( devtool) all my boxes falls apart. How can i make my boxes reponsiv so it stuck to the wrapper div and not falling apart, Thanks gain!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use props instead of state in your `Boxes` component. Then you can pass the required props from the `App` component.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Boxes from './components/calculator';


class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Boxes value={"Value 1"}/>
        <Boxes value={"Value 2"}/>
        <Boxes value={"Value 3"}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
  }


export default App;
```

Boxes.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './calculator.css';

class Boxes extends Component {
    render() { 
        const { value } = this.props // destructuring
        return (
            <div className="wrapper">
                <div className="firstBox">
                    <label htmlFor="text">
                       {value}
                    </label>
                    <input name="text" type="text" />                    
                </div>

            </div >

          );
    }
}

export default Boxes;
```

Comment: You might want to rename your `Boxes` component to `Box` as you are rendering only one box.

Answer (score 2):

You should pass a `prop` to your componente to be reuse. As you notice you are  using local component state in your component, like `const {value} = this.state` try the same approach but with props like `const {value} = this.props` and then passing that prop in the component usage like

```
<Boxes value={“label 1”}/>
<Boxes value={“label 2”}/>
```

That would work. Hope it help you

Remember you can use as many props you need and access them as the same way mention above

Comment: I am trying ti get the numbers from different input value and add them together and show them in another components I have created ( call <ShowResult /> ) I have same method for all the 3 components (onChange={this.getInputValue}) but I am not sure how to get the values from all the 3 input and sum them up together. thanks again for all the help I can get.

Comment: @Ayesha I left you a example about how to make what are you trying for check this out https://jsfiddle.net/johuder33/04fnrha2/

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
class Boxes extends Component {

    render() { 
        const { value } = this.props // value coming from props
        return (
            <div className="wrapper">
                <div className="firstBox">
                    <label htmlFor="text">
                       {value}
                    </label>
                    <input name="text" type="text" />                    
                </div>

            </div >

          );
    }
}

export default Boxes;
```

and in your app component something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Boxes from './components/calculator';


class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Boxes value={1}/> 
        <Boxes value={2}/>
        <Boxes value={3}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
  }


export default App;
```

Here is live demo [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8mxcmz)